# Сохранение файла в Firefox с помощью Selenium WD

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium, test-automation

Здравствуйте!

Я совсем недавно занимаюсь тестированием. Собственно, обойдя весь интернет, я никак не могу добиться того, чтобы при запуске теста не выскакивало окно с выбором "сохранить или открыть файл", когда на него ссылается тест.
Как я понял, с помощью Selenium webdriver нельзя добиться нажатия на кнопку "ОК" в окне браузера. Можно только настроить автоматическое скачивание. Файл PDF. В настройках самого браузера это не помогает.
не могли бы Вы подсказать какие-то возможные варианты? 
Буду крайне признателен.

Тест на Java

Comment: На кнопке ок по умолчанию должен быть фокус, поэтому вы можете нажать на нее с помощью java.awt.Robot.

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу 2 пути:

1. Создать профиль браузера, его настроить так что бы он файлы автоматически сохранял:

   `profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profilePath);`
2. Подгружать нужные настройки браузера при запуске селениума. Найти какие именно поля в about:config отвечают за автоматическое сохранение в категорию, а потом при запуске браузера селениума в нужном тесте подгружать эти изменения.

Делается это следующим путем (это только пример, нужно изменить на соответствующие поля и значения для ваших потребностей):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage",
"http://www.google.com");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Лично я бы опробовал бы сначала второй путь, а если не сработает(такое вполне возможно) -- пошел бы первым.

Answer (score 0):

Я решила это таким способом: создаешь профиль (firefox), настраиваешь автосохранение без подтверждения в нужную папку, при создании драйвера указываешь путь к профилю:

```
 profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("c:/Users/User1/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/qo8hmyya.eqrn")
```

Comment: a [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759256/selenium-firefox-profile-for-saving-a-file) вариант не пробовали ?